# How do I get a GWT menu popup to stay within the browser window?

Tags: gwt, menu, positioning

My GWT app uses a DockLayoutPanel for primary layout and the page itself does not scroll. I have a PopupPanel with a MenuBar and sometimes when a MenuItem is selected the sub menu bar goes off the bottom of the screen abruptly forcing a new scroll bar into the browser and messing up the layout.

How do I get the menu popup to behave nicely and reposition itself upward when the default positioning would put it out of the browser viewport (the way that PopupPanel.showRelativeTo(uiTarget) positioning works)?

In looking at the MenuBar source, it looks like all the layout is done in private methods, so I can't fix it in subclass, and I don't see any events I can listen to that would allow me to do the repositioning myself.

Comment: How it is going? Have you found the way to get sizes?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Web-Toolkit/browse_thread/thread/6185225fec64c091/4954d91d1461c71f?lnk=gst&q=context+menu#4954d91d1461c71f.

We've been using this strategy quite successfully for a while now.

Update: There is a bit more to be done. Specifically:

- Create a reposition() method, which:

  - Determines the max width of all the menu items
  - Checks the left edge of the menu + the max width; if greater than the Window's width, use "DOM.setStyleAttribute(elem, "left", left + "px");" to move the menu
  - Get the height of the menu; if top of the menu + height of the menu > Window's height, use "DOM.setStyleAttribute(elem, "top", top + "px");" to move it up.
- In the onAttach() method, use a deferred command to invoke the reposition() method.

Comment: The code posted in that thread is about right-click context menus in GWT 1.1. The only reference to menu positioning is this salient comment at the bottom of the code: "// TODO : if we're close to the bottom of the window, then offset the Y by the height of the to-be-drawn menu"

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't look closely enough. Our code extends the ideas in that post. I've edited my answer above to show the approach we take.

Comment: It does work to use reposition from a deferred command in the onAttach() method. However, the reposition takes place after the menu has been rendered and forced a relayout of the page around the new scrollbar. After the deferred command fixes it, another full page relayout occurs back to the way it was. I need a way to position the popup after it is attached but before it is set visible.

Comment: I haven't found a way to get sizes until after it's attached. You might be able to have a style on the menu such that it is not visible at first, do the calculations, then change the visibility. (Never tried this, so YMMV.)

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the popup just before it is shown, but after its size has been created. This way you have the width of the popup and could move it to another position:

```
@Override
public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent evt) {
    int x = evt.getNativeEvent().getClientX();
    int y = evt.getNativeEvent().getClientY();

    popupMenu.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PositionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
            if (x + offsetWidth > Window.getClientWidth()) {
                x = Window.getClientWidth() - offsetWidth;
            }

            //use same technique for height if you want for y, then
            setPosition(x, y);
        }
    });
}
```

(I know this is an old question, but still comes up if you search for this, so I thought of providing present solution)

Comment: Where do I put this method?

Comment: It depends. You could extend a `Composite` and override its existing `onContextMenu()`, you could as well `implement ContextMenuHander` and add it to a component via `.addHandler(new YourCustomContextMenuHandler())`.

Comment: Ah...I am using for a MenuBar
Thanks

Comment: @membersound I am having this same positioning problem in 2015, and I'm still wondering exactly where I would put this to intercept a MenuPopup created by a MenuBar. How do I access the `popupMenu` object so I can call `PopupPanel#setPopupPositionAndShow(PositionCallback)` given that it's an instance of a private class in MenuBar and also has private access in MenuBar?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think you have to extend the Popup class and override the `onContextMenu` method, but don't count me on that. I finally had quit gwt development due to that much annoying issues, and moved to `vaadin` (which is of course build on top of gwt, but overcomes all that issues). I can really recomment having a look into this!

Answer (score 0):

Emm...

It is an interesting question...

Looking at the [MenuBar](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.java?spec=svn8746&r=5308) source code... especially the method **openPopup**

```
 private void openPopup(final MenuItem item) {
    // Only the last popup to be opened should preview all event
    if (parentMenu != null && parentMenu.popup != null) {
      parentMenu.popup.setPreviewingAllNativeEvents(false);
    }

    // Create a new popup for this item, and position it next to
    // the item (below if this is a horizontal menu bar, to the
    // right if it's a vertical bar).
    popup = new DecoratedPopupPanel(true, false, "menuPopup") {
      {
        setWidget(item.getSubMenu());
        setPreviewingAllNativeEvents(true);
        item.getSubMenu().onShow();
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
        // Hook the popup panel's event preview. We use this to keep it from
        // auto-hiding when the parent menu is clicked.
        if (!event.isCanceled()) {

          switch (event.getTypeInt()) {
            case Event.ONMOUSEDOWN:
              // If the event target is part of the parent menu, suppress the
              // event altogether.
              EventTarget target = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
              Element parentMenuElement = item.getParentMenu().getElement();
              if (parentMenuElement.isOrHasChild(Element.as(target))) {
                event.cancel();
                return;
              }
              super.onPreviewNativeEvent(event);
              if (event.isCanceled()) {
                selectItem(null);
              }
              return;
          }
        }
        super.onPreviewNativeEvent(event);
      }
    };
    popup.setAnimationType(AnimationType.ONE_WAY_CORNER);
    popup.setAnimationEnabled(isAnimationEnabled);
    popup.setStyleName(STYLENAME_DEFAULT + "Popup");
    String primaryStyleName = getStylePrimaryName();
    if (!STYLENAME_DEFAULT.equals(primaryStyleName)) {
      popup.addStyleName(primaryStyleName + "Popup");
    }
    popup.addPopupListener(this);

    shownChildMenu = item.getSubMenu();
    item.getSubMenu().parentMenu = this;

    // Show the popup, ensuring that the menubar's event preview remains on top
    // of the popup's.
    popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {

      public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {

        // depending on the bidi direction position a menu on the left or right
        // of its base item
        if (LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL()) {
          if (vertical) {
            popup.setPopupPosition(MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteLeft() - offsetWidth
                + 1, item.getAbsoluteTop());
          } else {
            popup.setPopupPosition(item.getAbsoluteLeft()
                + item.getOffsetWidth() - offsetWidth,
                MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteTop() + MenuBar.this.getOffsetHeight()
                    - 1);
          }
        } else {
          if (vertical) {
            popup.setPopupPosition(MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteLeft()
                + MenuBar.this.getOffsetWidth() - 1, item.getAbsoluteTop());
          } else {
            popup.setPopupPosition(item.getAbsoluteLeft(),
                MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteTop() + MenuBar.this.getOffsetHeight()
                    - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

It is interesting to point the snippet as

```
...
popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {

      public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {

        // depending on the bidi direction position a menu on the left or right
        // of its base item
        if (LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().isRTL()) {
          if (vertical) {
            popup.setPopupPosition(MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteLeft() - offsetWidth
                + 1, item.getAbsoluteTop());
          } else {
            popup.setPopupPosition(item.getAbsoluteLeft()
                + item.getOffsetWidth() - offsetWidth,
                MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteTop() + MenuBar.this.getOffsetHeight()
                    - 1);
          }
        } else {
          if (vertical) {
            popup.setPopupPosition(MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteLeft()
                + MenuBar.this.getOffsetWidth() - 1, item.getAbsoluteTop());
          } else {
            popup.setPopupPosition(item.getAbsoluteLeft(),
                MenuBar.this.getAbsoluteTop() + MenuBar.this.getOffsetHeight()
                    - 1);
          }
        }
      }
    });

...
```

... so I may suppose there is a sense to play around MenuItem object especially its UIObject inherited methods like getAbsoluteLeft() and getAbsoluteTop(), of course ...

I would recommend to extend MenuItem something in this way

```
    //not tested
    public class MyMenuItem extends MenuItem
    {

    private MenuBar aSubMenuBar;//ItemMenu's submenu

    //...


    @Override
        public int getAbsoluteTop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.getAbsoluteTop()+movePopupTo();
        }


        private int movePopupTo()
    {
        int moveTo=0;

        int bottom=RootPanel.getBodyElement().getAbsoluteBottom();
        int rest=bottom -(super.getAbsoluteTop()+this.getaSubMenuBar().getOffsetHeight());
        if(rest<0)
        {
            moveTo=rest;
        }

        return moveTo;



    }



    public MenuBar getaSubMenuBar() {
            return aSubMenuBar;
        }

        public void setaSubMenuBar(MenuBar aSubMenuBar) {
            this.aSubMenuBar = aSubMenuBar;
        }


   //...

    }
```

It is not the final solution but a basic conception.

---

Report if that helped

Good luck

Comment: Won't work because the way in which the getAbsoluteTop call is done...the GWT code is call is limited to the MenuBar class implementation (because of `**MenuBar**.this.getAbsoluteTop()` syntax)